# change image pin maps

Tags: ios, mkmapview, swift2

What should I write in order to put a personal picture instead of the traditional red pin?

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let annView : MKPinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "currentloc")
    annView.pinTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    annView.animatesDrop = true
    annView.canShowCallout = true
    annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-8, 0)

    annView.autoresizesSubviews = true
    annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure) as UIView

    return annView
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MKAnnotationView` instead of `MKPinAnnotationView`, and then set its `image` property. I'd also suggest implementing the dequeue logic so that annotations can be reused:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let annotationIdentifier = "SomeCustomIdentifier" // use something unique that functionally identifies the type of pin

    var annotationView: MKAnnotationView! = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(annotationIdentifier)

    if annotationView != nil {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation
    } else {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)

        annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "annotation.png")

        annotationView.canShowCallout = true
        annotationView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-8, 0)

        annotationView.autoresizesSubviews = true
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure) as UIView
    }

    return annotationView
}
```

Comment: annotationIdentifier It gives me error. I replaced it with: String:"Random word"

Comment: Yep, use whatever is unique and functionally identifies the nature of the pin. Sorry if my intent there was unclear. I tweaked my code sample above.

Comment: Thanks :) friendly and helpful

Comment: as should be the image size (pixel) for the pins of the map?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. But, yes, depending on the nature of the image, you may choose to adjust `centerOffset` and `calloutOffset` accordingly.

Comment: Oh yeah. I know! I'm new here and I just started to develop. It is a new world for me.                           how should I do so that on Apple Watch, you just appears the map, it is located on the map and makes him see the places around him, already preset by me (example: nearby restaurant)?

Comment: I assume you'd just add a map to your watch storyboard. There is a map control you can add to your watch app. I'd suggest you refer to the WatchKit WWDC videos that talk about this. This is probably beyond the scope of what we should be trying to answer here in comments.

Comment: map already added to the storyboard and create the link on interface.controller but I have to understand how to set coordinates its location and how to get out right away places

Comment: I'd suggest you create a new question here on Stack Overflow, showing us what you've tried, describe what happened, and then describe what's wrong. But it's beyond the scope of this question.